# Can't enable WiFi on Vaio CW Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, wireless, vaio

I was using my WiFi with no problem, but an hour ago I switched it off from system settings and then tried to turn it on again, but no success. It's about 1 month I am using it and I had no problem with WiFi except this one.

I rebooted and went to Windows 7, but even that OS can't turn it on.
This is  `rfkill list all`:

```
0: sony-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: yes
1: sony-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: yes
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: yes
```

Comment: sudo rfkill unblock all. This command solved it. maybe not useful question!

Comment: It is a usefull solution! Solver my problems

Answer (score 1):

Enter you computer's BIOS and try "Load Setup Defaults" option to re-enable wireless. A few days ago, one of my friends had this problem and we solved it as I described to you.

Answer (score 0):

You've checked the switch for the wifi if there is one?  Also look for a Fn Key combination that will enable it for you.

Comment: there is a key in the front side, but the On and Off states make no change. it also has a LED that turns on when WIFI is enabled, and it's off all the time whether I turn the key on or off.